Cannot get rid of loose edges and vertices on plane

I have these random edges and vertices which I can box select and delete, but I am wondering if there is some way to get rid of them quickly since they are all on the same plane. I've tried all of the options in edge mode Shift-g but can't seem to select them all. Mesh cleanup -- loose edges and vertices does not work since they are not floating but sitting on the plane?
Thank you!

It would help to have your blend file with https://blend-exchange.com/ or at least screenshots of the geometry.

Goto edit mode and select few vertices/edges/faces of that plane, then press Ctrl + L to select all the lined vertices/edges/faces and the press Ctrl + I to invert selection (i.e, which are not linked to the selected plane) and now you have hopefully selected the vertices which you want to delete.
